# Issue while access contacts of android

Tags: java, android

I am new for android development. I am trying read and write contacts to android addressbook.

I tried following line of code for write name into android

```
public class SecondApp extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main); 

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Contacts.People.NAME, "Rishabh");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = cr.insert(People.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

but i am getting "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again" message.

what is wrong in it ?
How can i access contacts of android ?

---

Hi MannyNS thanks for reply
I have given write permission as you defined above.

but i am still getting the "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again", even when i start android its giving message "Process android.process media is not responding".

Can you suggest me whole procedure to read and write contacts to android ?
Do you have any sample code for it ?

Thanks 
Rishabh

Comment: Use LogCat and provide logs.
[Hope you added proper user permissions to manifest file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing system permissions to write a contact. 
Add this line to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

If your code has to read contacts, your applications will need "`android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`".

Full set of permissions flags can be found on [Android reference pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

Answer (score 1):

ViewContact.java:
Note: `getContacts()` is an user defined function

```
package com.android.ViewContact;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.database.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewContactAct extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView contactview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactview);
        Cursor mycursor=getContacts();
        while(mycursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String displayname=mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contactview.append("Name: ");
            contactview.append(displayname);
            contactview.append("\n");

        }
    }

    private Cursor getContacts()
    {
    Uri myuri=ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection=new String[]
                                   {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
                                   };

    String selection= ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
    + ("1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(myuri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
    sortOrder);


    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the contacts use the foll code:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/contactview" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In manifest file add the followinf entry: 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>`

the java code to display contact names from the contact book is given above: